# ReentrantLock .lock

Tags: java

El método `lock` de la clase `ReentrantLock`, bloquea el código que está en encerrado por el `lock`y el `unlock`. Si el código ya está bloqueado, el siguiente thread que intenta ejecutar ese código, espera a que se desbloquee o sigue ejecutando después del `unlock`?.
Mas abajo hago una pregunta mas.

```
public void transferir(int origen, int cFinal, double cantidad) {

    rt.lock();

    System.out.println("El thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " bloqueó el código." );

    try {
        if (cuentas[origen] < cantidad) {
            System.err.println("CANTIDAD INSUFICIENTE: Cuenta " + origen + ". Saldo: " + cuentas[origen] + ". Monto a transferir: " + cantidad );
            return;
        }else {
            System.err.println("Transferencia aceptada: ");
        }

        cuentas[origen] = cuentas[origen] - cantidad;

        System.out.printf("%10.2f de  %d para %d. ", cantidad, origen, cFinal);

        cuentas[cFinal] = cuentas[cFinal] + cantidad;

        System.out.printf("Saldo total: %10.2f\n", getSaldoTotal());
    } finally {
        System.out.println("El thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " desbloqueó el código." );
        rt.unlock();
    }

}
```

El out del código anterior:

```
El thread: Thread-0 bloqueó el código.
Transferencia aceptada: 
Transferencia aceptada: 
Transferencia aceptada: 
Transferencia aceptada: 
Transferencia aceptada: 
Transferencia aceptada: 
Transferencia aceptada: 
Transferencia aceptada: 
Transferencia aceptada: 
Transferencia aceptada: 
   2000,00 de  0 para 59. Saldo total:  200000,00
El thread: Thread-0 desbloqueó el código.
```

¿Porque imprime varias veces "Transferencia aceptada: "...?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que todos los hilos comparten la misma instancia del lock al ejecutar dicho método?

Comment: Mmm si. La instancia rt está creada en la clase del método transferir. Y dicha clase, es única y es pasada a cada thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no está en el uso del lock sino en el uso del stream para imprimir a consola. En unos casos utilizas `System.out` y en otros `System.err`. Cada uno de ellos son streams diferentes que terminan escribiendo la información sobre la consola, pero lo hacen a distinto tiempo y no tienen un orden exacto sobre cuál se mostrará primero. Para resolver esto, solo utiliza `System.out` en tu código. No es recomendable utilizar `System.err`. O mejor aún, utiliza una librería de logging como logback o log4j2 para evitar utilizar `System.out` y `System.err`.

Comment: Genial, cuando tenga la computadora lo pruebo y te confirmo el funcionamiento .

Comment: Si, era por el `System.err`